# How to use an interface as a parameter for another interface's function?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Suppose I have this two interfaces...

```
public interface ObjectInterface { /* empty interface */ }

public interface ObjectHandler
{
    void handle(ObjectInterface object);
}
```

...and also a concrete class which implements the ObjectInterface:

```
public class ConcreteObject implements ObjectInterface { /* ... */ }
```

**Why is this not allowed in Java?**

```
public class ConcreteHandler implements ObjectHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ConcreteObject object) // <-- ObjectInterface implementation
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

A `ConcreteObject` implements the `ObjectInterface` interface afterall.
**However, is there a way to design my classes in Java keeping this pattern of abstraction?**

Comment: Runtime covariance is not allowed with method parameters - only return types.

Comment: *"Why is this not allowed in Java?"* Why should it be allowed? You're actively restricting the passable objects for `ConcreteHandler#handle` since it only accepts `ConcreteObject` and not the broader type `ObjectInterface`. So it fails to correctly implement the `ObjectHandler` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterize `ObjectHandler` with the class of accepted `ObjectInterface`s:

```
public interface ObjectHandler<T extends ObjectInterface> 
{
    void handle(T object);
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
public class ConcreteHandler implements ObjectHandler<ConcreteObject>
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ConcreteObject object) // <-- now this works
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Under the hood, the `javac` compiler generates a method `void handle(ObjectInterface oi) { handle((ConcreteObject) oi); }` as a synthetic method for you +1

Answer (score 2):

Interface method is the contract,

```
void handle(ObjectInterface object);
```

Therefore the implementation of the interface should adhere to the contract. So it won't let you limit the object type it accepts.

```
handle(ConcreteObject object){...}
```

Above limits the input to the method, as its just a one implementation of `ObjectInterface`. Think what happens if there's another implementation called, `ConcreteObject2` which implements the `ObjectInterface`. According to your code `handle` method won't accepts the `ConcreteObject2` type objects.
If you want to keep the pattern you can use [java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're breaking the contract of the interface, and thus breaking the Liskov substitutioon principle.

The interface says: `handle()` can take any instance of ObjectInterface as argument. That's the contract: any implementation of `handle()` must accept any instance of ObjectInterface.

But the class says: `handle()` only accepts instances of ConcreteHandler.